# .NET mobile application, why are my cookies not being read in Safari browsers (Iphone)?

Tags: c#, iphone, cookies, safari

Here is my c# code

**UserLocation uc = UserLocation.ReadCookie(0);**
        if (uc != null)
        {
            userLoc1.Text = uc.City + ", " + uc.State;
        }
        else
        {
            userLoc1.Text = "Select a Location for Showtimes";
        }

```
  <div class="showUser">
    <a href="/Theatres" class="tabtheatres" id="select-location">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="icon"></div>
                        <div class="text">
                           <asp:Label ID="userLoc1" runat="server" clientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
        </div>
```

the c# code is being executed because it is putting the "Select Showtimes in the text", but apparently the uc ... user location which comes from a cookie is null, it should not be, and in debug, it isn't ... so the cookie clearly is not being read, but on Safari.

my research indicates that I could add this code to the web.config to aleviate this issue:

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" />
```

but will that affect other applications using this web.config?

Please advise.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

instead of setting session state to cookieless to true, try setting it to

```
<sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" />
```

this will force the the iis webserver to send the session state cookies regardless of browser profile.

Comment: two questions, what about <sessionState Cookieless = Autodetect />

Comment: also, I am nervous about affecting other parts of the application... is there any risk in putting this code in?

Comment: We have a legacy asp application where I work, that was completely borked when IE11 came out due to how it identified itself via useragent. After telling iis to force cookies regardless, all was well again. I can't speak for your application, but I *don't think* it should affect anything else